# Caller hijacking in Croatia

Tags: mobile, smartphone, cellular, caller-id

I got this issue today and I'm completely confused.

**Here is the story:**
I'm from Germany and on vacation in Croatia (all inside the EU with EU Roaming) with my German cellphone and German sim card.

I called my sister (+49 German number, also in Croatia) and my call seemed to get redirected. It sounds like a tape announcement. A woman saying "Hello" over and over again. But on the display there was the caller ID of my sister. Afterwards I called her again and got a similar tape with a guy saying "Ja" over and over again. The third time I called my call wents through and everything seemed to be okay. All the times with my sisters caller ID.

Later, I called my girlfriend (+49 German number, driving through Austria at this point) and got a similar behaviour but this time the person on the other end of the line was talking and it seemed they talked to another person. Like I'm interrupting a call of another person. It became creepy at this point. After that I called my girlfriend again and the call went through. Same with my girlfriends caller ID.

Then I tried to reproduce the issue and called my working phone (+49 German number, also in Croatia laying on my desk next to me). I was redirected to a completely different mailbox of a random woman. Same caller ID again. What the hell I thought. May my calls been hijacked but the caller ID on the display remained the same? Afterwards I deleted the entry from my contacts, so that the number is written there only but same result. The number remained the same, but I've been redirected to a completely random number.

**My question(s):**
So this was so confusing and creepy, that I decided to ask the community about this. Has anyone else experienced this behaviour before? Can anyone explain this behaviour? Have my calls possibly been hijacked? Does this sound like a problem of the Croatian telecomunication service/infrastructure or is there a high risk of a MITM attack?

Comment: Did you call `+49`/`0049` + `phone number` or did you accidently call `0` + `phone number`?

Comment: I called `+49` + `phone number` in all cases. This also worked properly the days before.

Comment: What connection did you have (ex. 2G, E, 3G, 4G, 5G...)?

Comment: It is probably just an error/disturbance of the provider, you can manually choose another roaming network as a quick fix.

Comment: I used 5G/4G/3G/2G and automated choosing of connection. 4G+ is used by my cellphone.

The provider network is also automatic choose but I'll try to set them manually now.

Thank you by the way.

Comment: Having used phones for over 40 years, this simply sounds like a call routing error. You should be asking the mobile provider companies about this.

Comment: @m4rc0 If its 4G+, its very unlikely (aka almost impossible) that someone intercepted your traffic between you and the cell phone tower